# My scanner isn't responding. It is connected to a SCSI interface using Windows XP

Tags: scanner, scsi

I have a Microtek ScanMaker 9600XL scanner. The best part about it is that it is 12x17 inches. Wowza! The worst part about it is that I've had it working at one point, with the same cable, same card, same computer, but have since re-installed Windows XP on it.

Currently it will turn on, and blink the Power and Ready lights. They should be solid.

I've done my best to find documentation for this, but all I've really gotten is the content on the [Microtek site](http://support.microtek.com/product_dtl_2.phtml?prod_id=26).

I've tried turning the scanner on, then the PC. Turning the PC on, then the scanner. When I try launching the software it pops up a dialog saying "ScanWizard Pro can't find any scanners! Use SCSI Check to find a scanner." I know the scanner has a pair of little buttons on the back. These cycle up/down a counter. I think it goes 0-7. Any thoughts on what that does, or how to proceed troubleshooting?

I think my next step is to try each of those numbers, and do both pc booted first, and scanner booted first for each of those numbers...

Comment: @ Bob "I think my next step is to try each of those numbers, and do both pc booted first, and scanner booted first for each of those numbers..." You're gonna have some fun... sorry I can't help you :(

Comment: i have used a similar model before, tempting isn't it? to try and troubleshoot by changing the SCSI location, it is not likly to be the actual problem, especially if you had it working before. What is the SCSI card your using? the sparrow?  Where does a trace of its connection end in the "device manager" ? Open device manager and set to show devices by connection, then follow the chain, where does it end?  is your PCI bus set to 100 in the bios? How is the scsi "terminated"? if I remember right termination was wary important with scsi.  Check your drivers stuff First.

Answer (score 0):

Doublecheck you've got the correct drivers installed for the SCSI card - the majority of scanner related ones will have additional software to install within Windows which will 'scan and find' devices attached.

As mentioned by Psychogeek - the numbers on the back are the SCSI ID number and not related to your issue at all, they would only enter into it if you are using multiple SCSI devices attached to the SCSI card.

See if you can find information relating to the SCSI card you have, some are 'self terminating' in which case you just connect a SCSI cable between the card and your device. Others require 'terminating' with a 'SCSI terminator' which will look like a dongle that will plug into the back of the scanner on a port exactly the same as the one used by your SCSI cable. If you have 2 ports the same (25 pin?) on the back of the scanner then they will be labeled something like 'PC' and 'Device' - to connect multiple SCSI devices to 1 card you used to 'daisychain' them together.

Hope that helps :)